# How to Execute an Existing Stored Procedure in DocumentDB?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I want to create a stored procedure in DocumentDB and use it whenever I need later on. To execute a stored procedure I need to know a storedProcedureLink. When I register stored procedure with CreateStoredProcedureAsync method I get the link, am I supposed to store this link somewhere myself if I want to execute this stored procedure later? Can I execute a stored procedure if all I know is a procedure name? From all the examples I found it seems that I need to create and register stored procedure right before I need to execute it, is it the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried this approach and it does not work.

```
client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery( link, String.Format( "select * from root r where r.id = '{0}'", "spname1" ) ).ToList(  ).FirstOrDefault( );
```

returns null

```
client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery( link, String.Format( "select * from root r" ) ).ToList( ).FirstOrDefault( );
```

returns correct stored procedure

```
{
    "id": "spname1",
    "body": "function() {  
        var context = getContext();
        var collection = context.getCollection();       
    }",
    "_rid": "XXX",
    "_ts": 1410449011.0,
    "_self": "XXX",
    "_etag": "XXX"
}
```

Comment: I believe `client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery( link, String.Format( "select * from root r where r.id = '{0}'", "spname1" ) ).ToList(  ).FirstOrDefault( );` queries for a stored procedure with id='{0}' rather than id='spname1'; you should query on `r.id = 'spname'` instead.

Comment: It does not make any sense as string.format will create appropriate string before send it to DocumentDB.

Comment: Ah yes, you're correct!

Interestingly, I just copy-pasted and ran `client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery( link, String.Format( "select * from root r where r.id = '{0}'", "spname1" ) ).ToList(  ).FirstOrDefault( );` and it returned my store procedure. Can you post more a larger code snippet to provide some more context?

Answer (score 5):

You can absolutely create the Stored Procedure beforehand and have it saved on the server for future use. You do not need to create it just before using it. This was for sample purposes only. We expect the majority of the time that the stored procedures will exist already and you just use them in your application.

You do need the SelfLink to execute the Stored Procedure.
One way to get this would be to query for the Stored Procedure (by Name), get the SelfLink and then use that to execute the stored procedure.

Querying for a Stored Procedure by name would look something like;

```
StoredProcedure sproc = client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(collection.StoredProceduresLink, "select * from root r where r.id = \"sproc name\"");
```

The resulting sproc variable will contain the SelfLink of the stored procedure you want to execute.

```
var result = client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync(sproc.SelfLink);
```

For comprehensive samples of how to work with Stored Procedures please see the  DocumentDB.Samples.ServerSideScripts project in the samples posted at;
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Azure-DocumentDB-NET-Code-6b3da8af

Comment: Why is this so hard to find... Every example that I found was about creating sprocs and that's the first one that is describing the most common scenario == executing a sproc and getting data...

Comment: If I try `StoredProcedure sproc = client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(collection.StoredProceduresLink, "select * from root r where r.id = \"sproc name\"");` in Visual Studio 2015, the compiler complains *Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<dynamic>' to 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoredProcedure'*

Comment: Ryan CrawCour, Thanks for the answer. The samples link now 404's.

Answer (score 2):

> From all the examples I found it seems that I need to create and register stored procedure right before I need to execute it, is it the case?

No.  Stored procedure creation and registration does not have to happen during execution.

The samples are educational, but do not offer real-world patterns.  See the [DocumentManagement basic CRUD operations](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-net/blob/master/samples/code-samples/DocumentManagement/Program.cs).  Samples also assume a single collection too.  See the [Partitioning basic CRUD operations](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-net/blob/master/samples/code-samples/Partitioning/Program.cs).

While I applaud the DocumentDB adaption of SQL coding conventions, the usage pattern *currently* falls short for .NET developers.  The decade old pattern of creating CRUD stored procedures in SQL Server and then calling them by name via ADO.NET or a TableAdapter in a DataSet does not work in the DocumentDB.

> Can I execute a stored procedure if all I know is a procedure name?

Yes, but it's not pretty:

```
StoredProcedure storedProcedure = this.DocumentClient.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(new Uri(collection.StoredProceduresLink)).Where(p => p.Id == "GetPunkRocker").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

When using a PartitionResolver, things get more complicated:

```
    public async Task<PunkRocker> GetPunkRockerAsync(string partitionKey)
    {
        foreach (string collectionLink in this.PartitionResolver.ResolveForRead(partitionKey))
        {
            DocumentCollection collection = this.DocumentClient.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(new Uri(this.Database.SelfLink)).Where(c => c.SelfLink == collectionLink).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

            if (collection == null)
            {
                // Log...
                continue;
            }

            StoredProcedure storedProcedure = this.DocumentClient.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(new Uri(collection.StoredProceduresLink)).Where(p => p.Id == "GetPunkRocker").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

            if (storedProcedure == null)
            {
                // Log...
                continue;
            }

            PunkRocker punkRocker = await this.DocumentClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<PunkRocker>(new Uri(storedProcedure.SelfLink), partitionKey);

            if (punkRocker != null)
            {
                return punkRocker;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: So the stored procedure gets executed once for each partition? What if the query inside the stored proc is doing something like select * from root and returning the first three?

Comment: Re: "find a sproc by name": isn't this a bit cleaner? Are there downsides? `_client.ReadStoredProcedureAsync(
                    UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri(databaseId, collectionId, sprocId)`

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the SP in the DB first in .NET SDK

```
StoredProcedure storedProcedure = Client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(GetCollection(eColl).SelfLink).Where(c => c.Id == "SP name").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Microsoft is now providing a few samples on how to execute stored procedures:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.executestoredprocedureasync?view=azure-dotnet